# Nextjs: Error when config layout per page with typescript include getServerSildeProps

Tags: typescript, next.js

I use `ts` for my `Nextjs`. I also config layout per page base on [Layout per page with typescript by Vercel](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/layouts#with-typescript)

this is `pages/_app.tsx`

```
export type NextPageWithLayout<P = {}, IP = P> = NextPage<P, IP> & {
  getLayout?: (page: ReactElement) => ReactNode
}

type AppPropsWithLayout = AppProps & {
  Component: NextPageWithLayout
}

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppPropsWithLayout) {
  const getLayout = Component.getLayout ?? ((page) => <MainLayout>{page}</MainLayout>)
  //MainLayout is default, unless Page pass Layout

  return getLayout(<Component {...pageProps} />)
}
```

this is `pages/about.tsx`:

```
type Nav = {
  id: number
  id_parent_category: number | null
  name: string
  status: number
}

const About: NextPageWithLayout = ({ data }: { data: Array<Nav> }) => {
  return <div></div>
}

About.getLayout = (page: ReactElement) => {
  //pass a NON default layout
  return <SecondLayout>{page}</SecondLayout>
}
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async () => {
  const response = await axiosCT.get('/category')
  let data: Array<Nav> = [] //|undefined = undefined

  if (response && response.code === 200) {
    data = response.data
  }
  return {
    props: {
      data,
    },
  }
}
```

The problem:

[image]

The `getServerSideProps` cause the error. If I don't use `getServerSideProps` for this page, the `error` disapear.

How can i fix that?